# Need to create a 5 minute interval in trino for a date and show an aggregate function

Tags: sql, database, trino

data table format

| timestamp | stream_id |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 12:30:29.928 | 123. |
| 2021-01-01 01:30:29.928 | 124. |
| 2021-01-01 05:30:29.928 | 223. |
| 2021-01-01 01:23:29.928 | 134. |

expected output

| day | timestamp. | count(stream_id) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01. | 12:00. | 5. |
| 2021-01-01. | 12:05. | 18 |
| 2021-01-01. | 12:10. | 39 |
| 2021-01-01. | 12:20. | 90 |
| 2021-01-01. | 12:25. | 45 |
| 2021-01-01. | 12:30. | 76 |
| 2021-01-01. | 12:35. | 93 |

Comment: you definitely  will not get the specified output from the shown sample data =)

Answer (score 0):

You can use some [date manipulation](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html) to split timestamp into parts and then use them to group data and perform aggregation:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset(timestamp, stream_id) AS (
 values (timestamp '2021-01-01 12:30:29.928', 123),
    (timestamp '2021-01-01 01:30:29.928', 124),
    (timestamp '2021-01-01 05:30:29.928', 223),
    (timestamp '2021-01-01 01:23:29.928', 134),
    (timestamp '2021-01-01 01:24:29.928', 135),
    (timestamp '2021-01-01 01:26:29.928', 136)
)

-- query
select day,
    date_add('minute', 5*grp, day) ts, -- construct the 5 minute group back
    count(*) cnt
from
    (select date_trunc('day', timestamp) day,
        date_diff('millisecond', date_trunc('day', timestamp), timestamp) / (5 * 60 * 1000) grp,
        stream_id
    from dataset)
group by day, grp;
```

Output:

| day | ts | cnt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2021-01-01 12:30:00.000 | 1 |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2021-01-01 01:25:00.000 | 1 |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2021-01-01 05:30:00.000 | 1 |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2021-01-01 01:30:00.000 | 1 |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2021-01-01 01:20:00.000 | 2 |

Use `date_format` if needed to turn timestamps into needed representations.